# How to access values of row being deleted in RowDeleting event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, rowdeleting

I am trying to save a little bit of information before I delete it from the database. I'm using an asp gridview. I'm trying to retrieve the values from the row being deleted with the RowDeleting event. However, I've been extremely unsuccessful.

```
Protected Sub gv1_RowDeleting(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles   gv1.RowDeleting
   Dim a As String = gv1.Columns(0).ToString
   Dim b As String = gv1.SelectedRow.RowIndex.ToString
   Dim c As String = gv1.Rows(a).Cells(0).Text
End Sub
```

a ends up being the header row first column. b errors out. I've tried a bunch of different things and can't come up with a row index. I would have figured this event would access only the row being deleted. Here is my gridview declaration:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableViewState="false"
            DataSourceID="ds1" EmptyDataText="NO ROWS FOUND" CssClass="gridView" DataKeyNames="id" GridLines="None">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="totalsd" HeaderText="SD" SortExpression="totalsd" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="freesd" HeaderText="FREE" SortExpression="freesd" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="deleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `e` as `System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs`. You can then get the row index with `e.RowIndex`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this sample way  like use `RowCommand`

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="DelButton" runat=server Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" CausesValidation=False CommandArgument='<%# Databinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

and in vb file Change

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand

        Dim MyConn1 As New OleDbConnection(Your Connection string)
        Dim cmdDelete As OleDbCommand

        If e.CommandName = "Delete" Then
             cmdDelete = New OleDbCommand("Delete from table" & _
                                               "Where id= " & e.CommandArgument.ToString() & ";", MyConn1)
            MyConn1.Open()
            cmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MyConn1.Close()
            BindAutoMake()

        End If
    End Sub
```

**N.B :    Make sure you still have Row_deleting event handler method but Empty without any code. Otherwise it will gives you error.**